# Visual Studio C++ ambigous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, operators

Edit: I posted the whole class (striped a few for the error irrelevant things out)

I made following class:

```
class packet
{public:char *  buffer;
    int     size;
    int     data;

    packet();
    packet(packet &text, int length=-1);
    packet(char * text, int length=-1);
    packet(int val);
    packet(char c);
    packet(double d);
    packet(float f);

    ~packet();

    packet &    operator=       (packet &text);
    packet      operator+       (packet &text);
    packet &    operator+=      (packet &text);
    packet &    operator|=      (packet &text);
    bool        operator==      (packet &text);
    bool        operator*=      (packet &text);
    bool        operator!=      (packet &text);

                operator char*  () const;
                operator int    () const;
                operator float  () const;
    char        operator []     (int pos)  const;
};
```

And I use the class like this:

```
    packet p = packet();
```

or

```
return packet();
```

And Visual Studio gives me this error:

```
test.cpp(162): error C2668: 'packet::packet' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
...packet.h(26): could be 'packet::packet(float)'
...packet.h(23): or       'packet::packet(int)'
...packet.h(22): or       'packet::packet(char *,int)'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here ? Why is this ambigous ?

PS:  I think it has to do with the 4 operators at the bottom but I am a little hazy with overloading those kind of operators...

**Solution: I got it working by marking some constructors as explicit:**

```
class packet
{public:char *  buffer;
    int     size;
    int     data;

    packet();
    packet(packet &text, int length=-1);
    explicit packet(char * text, int length=-1);
    explicit packet(int val);
    explicit packet(char c);
    explicit packet(double d);
    explicit packet(float f);

    ~packet();

    packet &    operator=       (packet &text);
    packet      operator+       (packet &text);
    packet &    operator+=      (packet &text);
    packet &    operator|=      (packet &text);
    bool        operator==      (packet &text);
    bool        operator*=      (packet &text);
    bool        operator!=      (packet &text);

                operator char*  () const;
                operator int    () const;
                operator float  () const;
    char        operator []     (int pos)  const;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your whole code?

Comment: I'm sure it is not the whole code. My guess is that he is passing either `0` or `NULL` to the constructor, something like `packet(0)` or `packet(NULL)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the guy has much more optional parameters than that in the actual code.

Comment: Did you say `packet(0)`?

Comment: But he's saying he has `return packet();`. Which wouldn't give an error.

Comment: @Luchian: That obviously can't be the case, because `packet()` *can not be ambiguous*.

Comment: Why I said it wouldn't give an error.

Comment: @Xeo: It can indeed be ambiguous if there are multiple constructors that take no arguments- for example, a constructor which can take an argument that is defaulted.

Comment: Does your class have conversion operators?

Comment: @DeadMG: Sorry for assuming that atleast the shown constructors were the ones the OP really has in his code. :)

Comment: @HardCoder Could you please post the entire packet file?

Comment: Thanks for the many replies. I really do a "return packet();" without any parameter which is why I find this so puzzling. And I have no other constructors or functions except for a few operator overloads like "packet & operator = ( packet &x);" and  "packet operator + ( packet &x);". I really don't know why I get an error.

Comment: Turned out to be a nice little puzzle, but it would have been easy enough and avoided a lot of frustration to give a ready-to-compile example right from the start.

Comment: I thought it was something very simple ( well, it was ;-) ) that posting the whole code wasn't necessary. Next time I will post a usable code snippet from the start though, to avoid confusion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the error really occurs at the place where you try to assign the result of the function to a new variable, the problem could be your copy constructor. You should make the `packet&` in `const` so that it can be used with temporary objects:

```
packet(const packet & text, int length=-1);
```

The other constructors might come into play in this case if your class is implicitly convertible to `int`, `float`,....

Due to such issues it is usually advisable to not add unnecessary conversion operators and mark constructors as `explicit` to avoid unexpected implicit conversions.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me solve my problem. I marked several of the constructors as explicit and it compiled and works !

Comment: Note that MSVC 2010 gives a good message about this at `/W4` if the conversion operators are left out of the mix (in part because MSVC will do something non-standard): `C:\temp\test.cpp(35) : warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'argument' : conversion from 'packet' to 'packet &', A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue; copy constructor takes a reference to non-const`

Comment: @HardCoder: it would probably be a good idea to mark many of your `packet&` parameters as `const`.